# Can you connect to a windows domain from a seperate network?

Tags: windows, domain, active-directory, ldap, computer-name

I was wondering if you can connect to a domain from a separate network... Reason being is because I have a clients laptop here with me and I was wondering if I can join their domain from here at my workplace...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the domains configuration.  Generally, most will be configured so that you can join via a VPN.